# Configuring JDeveloper to use PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jdeveloper

I have a Java project which uses Struts and Hibernate. I am using PostgreSQL as the database for the project.

I have imported the `.jws` file in JDeveloper. All the `java` and `jsp` files are imported to the project.

When I tried to run the project multiple errors came out. I think it's due to a database connection failure.

Do I need to configure pgsql with the project?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PostgreSQL version? Platform (Windows/Linux)? What's the *exact text of the error messages*? (If they're long put them on a pastebin site and link to them here). Can you connect to PostgreSQL via `psql` or `PgAdmin-III`? As it stands there is not enough detail to answer your question.

Comment: *"multiple errors came out*" is not a valid PostgreSQL error. And I'm pretty sure it isn't an error JDeveloper is showing you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide more info on what the errors are.

But some common problem in JDeveloper when using the bundled server to test is that (if you are using datasources) you have to place the driver jars in the server lib folder or declare it as a Library by going to Tools->Manage Libraries.

If you post what errors are you receiving and how are you connecting to the database we might be able to help you a little more.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add the postgreSQL jdbc jar files to your project and to the embedded WebLogic instance.
Tell us the specific error you are getting and we'll help you more.